# Implementing Branch.io Referral system

Tags: branch.io

Has anyone successfully implement branch.io referral system on mobile apps? I can't seems to find any guide anywhere on their website anymore on referrals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Branch is currently revamping the referrals system and will be introducing a new updated one shortly. You will be notified on any product updates via your mail address as registered on Branch.

As of now, the referrals guide on our documentations page has been taken down for necessary updates to be made.

If you need any assistance in setting up your referrals engine, feel free to raise a ticket at support@branch.io .

Comment: Meanwhile is there any documentation available so I can set it up first?

Comment: Currently, the referrals documentation has been taken down for necessary updates to be made. it will be available when the latest referral engine releases.

Comment: is there any tentative date we are looking at?

Comment: Hi @JGSG currently we don't have any ETA on this